# Would it make sense to filter air through oil?

Tags: purification, liquids, filtering

I have seen water-based air purifiers, which work by having air bubble through water supposedly leaving water-soluble molecules behind.
I understand that this concept also humidifies the air due to the contact with water.

Would there be any benefit in doing the same thing, but using oil as the liquid instead?
Does the air contain oil-soluble molecules & would the air become "oily" (in contrast to humid)

Unfortunately my english lacks the correct terms for this and any searches result in information about how to change oil filters in cars.

Comment: The compounds in the oil that might end up in the exhaust are the volatile fraction (by definition). Oil might be used in a pump mechanism as a lubricant or sealant, but then shouldn't contain large amounts of volatile substances. Vacuum pumps that use oil or other substances to capture volatile substances are called entrapment pumps. A diffusion pump might use oil, but not as you have proposed.

Comment: Oil definitely traps some molecules in air. When you run a vacuum distillation using an oil pump, you place a cold trap between the still and the pump so you don't have to change the oil so often.

Comment: It will A) Smell liek the oil you use and B) Carry some oil with it. I have used straight air from an air compressor to breathe in a confined space and yeah I am fine after 4 hours of it but it smells and tastes/feels like oily air. You won't like that air